# Scrolling to a item in horizontal list view inside vertical list view in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have some kind of tab bar inside. I've implemented it with horizontal ListView. Whole page content is inside the vertical scroll view.

When clicking on the "Third tab" I need to scroll to it to show the full name. Problem is that ListView doesn't have scroll-to-item method. Some other possiblities:

- `Scrollable.ensureVisible(context)` almost works but the problem is that it will scroll vertical list too which I don't want. And I don't see a way to prevent that.
- Using scrollable_positioned_list package, will scroll as the item should be in the first position resulting in a huge overscroll bounce on iOS device. This method is missing something like `ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.keepVisibleAtStart` that ensureVisible has.
- The items are not fixed width so that rules out several solutions.

[image]

Comment: Same situation here... Did you find any solution?

Comment: Same question. For now, I can only with more calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this somewhat by setting the `alignmentPolicy` attribute within `Scrollable.ensureVisible` based on the index of the currently selected `ListView` item and the newly selected `ListView` item. With the `alignmentPolicy` being set to `ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.keepVisibleAtEnd` if the newly selected item's index is greater than the currently selected item's index, otherwise set it to `ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.keepVisibleAtStart`. Additionally, the `itemBuilder` must create each item with a new `GlobalKey`, shown in the code below, this allows the context to be grabbed from each individual `ListView` item.

**Bare in mind that for my solution I have used `ListView.builder`.**

<strike>[Note]
The only issue is that if you select an item that has a lower index than the currently selected item, but the newly selected item needs to scroll right to have it in view, then it will not scroll to have it in view, and vice versa.</strike>

E.g. If the currently selected index is 5, and the newly selected index is 3, and the ListView needs to scroll to the right to have the item in view, then the scroll will not occur.

However, if the currently selected index is 5, and the newly selected index is 3, and the ListView needs to scroll to the left to have the item in view, then the scroll will occur.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHyhm.gif)

```
List<Widget> tabs = [YourTabWidget(), YourTabWidget(), YourTabWidget()];
int activeTabIndex = 0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView(
    children: [
      ListView.builder(
        itemCount: tabs.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          GlobalKey dataKey = GlobalKey();
          return GestureDetector(
            key: dataKey,
            onTap: () {
              Scrollable.ensureVisible(
                dataKey.currentContext!,
                alignmentPolicy: index > activeTabIndex
                    ? ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.keepVisibleAtEnd
                    : ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.keepVisibleAtStart,
              );
              setState(
                () {
                  activeTabIndex = index;
                },
              );
            },
            child: tabs[index],
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

**Edit**: Resolved the previously mentioned issue by calling `Scrollable.ensureVisible` twice, one time with `alignmentPolicy: ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.keepVisibleAtEnd` and straight after calling it with `alignmentPolicy: ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.keepVisibleAtStart`

So instead of:

```
onTap: () {
              Scrollable.ensureVisible(
                dataKey.currentContext!,
                alignmentPolicy: index > activeTabIndex
                    ? ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.keepVisibleAtEnd
                    : ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.keepVisibleAtStart,
              );
              setState(
                () {
                  activeTabIndex = index;
                },
              );
            },
```

It will be:

```
onTap: () {
              Scrollable.ensureVisible(
                dataKey.currentContext!,
                alignmentPolicy: ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.keepVisibleAtEnd
              );
              Scrollable.ensureVisible(
                dataKey.currentContext!,
                alignmentPolicy: ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.keepVisibleAtStart
              );
              setState(
                () {
                  activeTabIndex = index;
                },
              );
            },
```